# Rewrite a query to sort data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, order-by

I have a stored procedure that uses two main tables and some other tables to get the required customer data. One of the parameters passed into the SP contains an xml with customerids that are shredded and stored in a table variable inside the SP. This table is then used to join to the other two main tables to get the required info. The following are the main tables:

`tblProduct` - This table contains all the product information. It has more than 100 million rows and more than 70 columns.

`tblProductCustomer` - This table contains information about the customers and the products that they ordered. This has more than 100 million rows.

For any given customer(s), my task is to find the top 1500 rows `ordered by productDateModified Desc.`

Here are sample structures of those tables and the query I have to use. I have to select 33 columns from the product table as my result set:

```
    Insert Into @customers
    --shred the customers xml parameter passed in
    
    Create Table tblProduct
    (
    productId uniqueidentifier primary key,
    productName varchar(100)
    productModifiedDate datetime
   --67 more columns
    )
    Go
    
    Create Table tblProductCustomer
    (
    prodKey Int Identity(1,1) primary key,
    productId uniqueidentifier,
    customerId uniqueidentifier
    )
    
    Select top 1500 --33 columns from product table
    From tblProduct pr
    join tblProductCustomer prc
    on pr.productId = prc.productId
    join @tblcustomer c
    on c.customerId = prc.customerId
    order by pr.productModifiedDate desc
```

This is the problem I'm facing: Because of the way our tables are structured I have to get all the products related to the customer from the product table and then do a top 1500 ordered by productDateModified Desc. This works well in cases where there are not many rows for a customer. But there are cases where multiple customer ids are sent in and sometimes all them together have more than million rows in the product table. If I use the above query, then it has to get all the millions of rows, sort them by productDateModified desc and then do a top 1500. But this takes way too long to execute (3 to 4 minutes). So I decided to rewrite the query.

This is what I did:

```
create table #products (productId uniqueidentifier, productModifiedDate datetime)
create nonclustered index on #products(productModifiedDate) include(productId)

Select top 1500 pr.productId, pr.productModifiedDate 
into #products
From tblProduct pr
join tblProductCustomer prc
on pr.productId = prc.productId
join @tblcustomer c
on c.customerId = prc.customerId
order by pr.productModifiedDate desc

Select --33columns from tblProduct table
from tblProduct pr
join #products temp
on pr.productId = temp.productId
order by temp.productModifiedDate desc
```

Instead of doing an order by when selecting 33 rows, I did an order by with just the product id and stored that information in a temp table. Now that I only have the products that I'm interested in, in the temp table, I joined it to the main product table to get all the other columns that I need. This improved the speed a lot because I was getting back the results in under a minute for customers with huge data whereas it was taking me at least 3 to 4 minutes earlier. But this method adds overhead for customers who have less than 1500 rows in the product table because now I'm hitting the product table twice. I was wondering if there was a better way to rewrite this query.

Comment: Two red flags I'm reading here: 1. XML shredding and 2. Table variable. Not sure what the XML input looks like or how you're shredding it, but since that comes before the actual `JOIN`s etc, it *may* be ok. You can comment out the rest of your code in your procedure and just run the XML shredding part, and see how long that takes by itself. Shouldn't be more than a few seconds ideally. Table variables, especially when `JOIN`ed to, are notorious for being bad for performance, and especially if they have a lot of rows in them, because they have poor statistics. Temp tables are usually better.

Comment: @j.d. the xml shredding takes milliseconds and I have the same issues with temp tables.

Comment: That's good about the XML shedding. Regardless you should almost always use Temp Tables over Table variables, you may have other issues (such as consuming extra server resources unnecessarily) that could be affecting your server even if the runtime is the same either way for you specific query. In any case, you should upload the actual execution plan of your query to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) if you want help with performance tuning.

Comment: What indexes do you have on `tblProduct`? Have you considered an index `(productModifiedDate) INCLUDE (33OtherColumnsHere)` and do you really need all those columns anyway?

Comment: @Charlieface tblProduct table has productId as the clustered index and primary key and also has an index on ProductModifiedDate INCLUDE(productId, 2 other columns). I did not think about the index you suggested. The problem I have is even though I have an index on productModifiedDate it won't be used since the way customers are linked to the products is through the productCustomer table. The index being sorted by productModifiedDate doesn't help because different customers will have different dates. So it always does a clustered index seek on productId. Unfortunately, I need all the columns :(

Comment: Instead of *describing* your indexes, show us the full definition for them. We also need the indexes on the other tables, as well the execution plan. I note that your first query appears to be doing something different from what you say: it's not giving 1500 rows *per customer*, just 1500 rows total. Which do you want?